# R function to move specific PDF files from one folder to another

Tags: r

There are 6000 PDF files in one folder, but I need 300 PDF files from it. How to move those 300 pdf files out of 6000 to another folder?

Comment: do you have any key by which you can select the 300 PDFs or do you want to select them at random?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If both folders are on the same volume, `file.rename()` should be able to move the files.  If they are on different volumes it's worth a try, but I wouldn't expect success.

Comment: You'll need some kind of criteria to enumerate the names of the 300 PDFs as mentioned by @jyr, but the function `fs::file_move` is probably what you're looking for